# How can I make a loop execute when a variable even, and do something else when it's odd?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm currently developing a tic-tac-toe game, and I need some help.

I'm trying to make my loop run if the variable `xoro` is even(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc.), like make an X and do something different if it is odd(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc.), like make an O. Right now I am just figuring out how to trade off turns. I have looked at other questions, and googled the topic with no luck.

```
int[] even = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
int xoro = 1;

if (xoro == even[]) { // troublesome line
        System.out.println("an even number is " + xoro);
        XORO++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("an odd number is " + xoro);
        XORO++;
    }
}
```

Do I have to use `if(XORO == 2 || XORO == 4 || XORO == 6...` etc.? I know there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: You could use a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) like `boolean checkEven(int)`

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan Probably better to check a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     int[] even = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 21};
            for (int XORO = 0; XORO < even.length; XORO++) {
                if (even[XORO] % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("an even number is " + even[XORO]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("an odd number is " + even[XORO]);
                }
            }

output:-

an even number is 2
an even number is 4
an even number is 6
an even number is 8
an even number is 10
an even number is 12
an even number is 14
an even number is 16
an even number is 18
an even number is 20
an odd number is 21
```

Comment: Hi Tom G. I have tested it on my machine.

Comment: For checking  the odd number case I have added one extra odd number in array i.e 21.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Dave Newton, I have fixed the program, and the answer is so:

```
int XORO = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if(XORO%2==0){
            System.out.println("an even number is " + XORO);
            XORO++;
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("an odd number is " + XORO);
            XORO++;
            }
        }
```

and the output is how i desired:

```
an odd number is 1
an even number is 2
an odd number is 3
an even number is 4
an odd number is 5
an even number is 6
an odd number is 7
an even number is 8
an odd number is 9
an even number is 10
an odd number is 11
an even number is 12
an odd number is 13
an even number is 14
an odd number is 15
an even number is 16
an odd number is 17
an even number is 18
an odd number is 19
an even number is 20
```

Comment: Yup, there you go.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple for loop for this

```
int[] even = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};
for(int i=0;i<even.length;i++)
{
if(even[i]%2==0)
{ System.out.println("an even number is " + XORO);}
else
{System.out.println("an odd number is " + XORO);}
}
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what %2 does?

Comment: @TomG. Modulo operator-check the Javas docs. Obviously you don't want to run it against your array of even numbers, though-this would replaced the need to have an array of even numbers.

Comment: is there a method that checks whether something is even or odd?

Comment: @TomG. That's what the modulo is doing.

Comment: @TomG. Method? Sure, if you write one. The `x % 2 == 0` is an *expression* checking if `x` is even.

Comment: @DaveNewton So are you saying i should delete the array of even numbers?

Comment: This code is still incorrect-it's the increasing count that's being checked for even/odd, not the content of the array. They're all even.

Comment: @DaveNewton Wow! i just fixed the program, and it ran perfectly! I will post the answer now.

Comment: @TomG. If you're just checking in a loop if the numbers from 1-20 are odd or even, yes. It's not entirely clear if that's what you're trying to do.